# Can't convert string into integer

Tags: c++, string, integer

I am new to C++ and the problem is that I can't convert string into integer; Could you help please?

```
    container *beg = NULL;
    container *insert;
    insert = new container;

    std::ifstream  data(filename);
    std::string line;
    std::getline(data, line);

    for (container *i = insert; std::getline(data, line); i = i->nextCont)
    {
        std::stringstream lineStream(line);
        std::string cell;
        i->ID = atoi(cell.c_str);
        for (box *j = i->beginBox; std::getline(lineStream, cell, ';'); j = j->next)
        {
            j->apples = atoi(cell.c_str);
        }
    }
    return beg;
```

Errors are :

Error   4   error C3867: 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>::c_str': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_string,std::allocator>::c_str' to create a pointer to member e:\labs\3.container\3.container\class.cpp   109 1   3.container

Error   5   error C3867: 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>::c_str': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_string,std::allocator>::c_str' to create a pointer to member e:\labs\3.container\3.container\class.cpp   112 1   3.container

Comment: Thank you guys. Sorry for a stupid question. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe add parentheses to actually call it:

```
j->apples = atoi(cell.c_str());
                           ^^^
```

Also, you probably want to look into other ways to convert strings to integers, like [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or `strtol` or `istringstream`.

Answer (score 1):

`c_str` is a method on a string, so you need to call it like `cell.c_str()` to tell the compiler is a method, not a class member

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  container *beg = NULL;
container *insert;
insert = new container;

std::ifstream  data(filename);
std::string line;
std::getline(data, line);

for (container *i = insert; std::getline(data, line); i = i->nextCont)
{
    std::stringstream lineStream(line);
    std::string cell;
    i->ID = atoi(cell.c_str());
    for (box *j = i->beginBox; std::getline(lineStream, cell, ';'); j = j->next)
    {
        j->apples = atoi(cell.c_str());
    }
}
return beg;
```